# Different routes for landing page and dashboard in Angular2

Tags: angular, routes, router-outlet

I am developing a blog site with Angular 2. 
Now I want to show a signup/login form on landing page when user visit my site only signup form will show no menu or header.

Now when user logged in they will redirect to /dashboard and see the menus and header and content

Now how to start. Is it possible to use two router-outlets?

Signup layout image: http://prntscr.com/dwh1qg

Dashboard layout : http://prntscr.com/dwh2lp

Answer (score 0):

Each component can contain router-outlet.

I think that you should create `App` component which would contain routes to `Dashboard` component and `Default` component. In those components you should also put router-outlet and create different routes.

This way you can have different templates for each group of components.

```
@RouteConfig([
   { path: '/dahsboard/...', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
   { path: '/...', name: 'Default', component: DefaultComponent }
])
export class AppComponent
```

Your template for this component can be as simple as `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Then your child components can have different routing and different templates.

```
@RouteConfig([
   { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
   { path: '/sign-up', name: 'SignUp', component: SignupComponent }
])
export class DefaultComponent
```

And it's template should also contain `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Comment: i think we dont use @RouteConfig anymore in Angular2 (Angular cli).

Comment: @RakeshRoy it depends on version, with newest there is no `@RouteConfig`, but I wrote it as an example.